# Checking to see if a word has multiple letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to check to see if there are multiple letters in a word (every word is 5 letters) and i have an array of 8938 words in a variable called library.

```
           function checkLetters(word){
                var constant = 0;
                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                    for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
                        if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j)){
                            return false;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(compPrompt == 5 && checkLetters(compChoice) == true){
                console.log(checkLetters(compChoice));
                $('.right').append('<p id="winQuestion">Is "'+compFinalChoice+'" your word?');
                $('.right').append('<div class="yesNo" id="yesQ"><p>Yes</p></div>');
                $('.right').append('<div class="yesNo" id="noQ"><p>No</p></div>');
                $('#yesQ').click(function() {
                    alert('Your word is "'+compFinalChoice+'". You lose!');
                    document.location.reload(true);
                });
                $('#noQ').click(function() {
                    $('.yesNo').remove();
                    $('#winQuestion').remove();
                    var splitCompChoice = compFinalChoice.split('');
                    var constant = 0;
                    var possibleAnswers = [];
                    for(var k=0;k<8939;k++){
                        for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
                            if(library[k].indexOf(splitCompChoice[i]) > -1){
                                constant++;
                                if(constant = 5 && checkLetters(library[k]) == true){
                                    possibleAnswers.push(library[k]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                });
            }
```

I am having 2 problems with the code. One it is getting past the `if(compPrompt == 5 && checkLetters(compChoice) == true){` when `checkLetters(compChoice)` isn't true and two it is telling me `library[k]` isn't defined.

Comment: When you say "multiple letters" do you mean if the word has duplicates letters?

Comment: yes but that problem was fixed below, i have an array of words call library and when I click #noQ it tells me that library[k] isn't defined

Comment: @btse he meant `repeating` letters - his code speaks better than his words :)

Comment: Ok, well here's another tip then. I suppose for 5 letters your current algorithm isn't that bad, but in general it is still O(n^2). A better solution is to create a boolean array where each letter correlates to an index in the array. Iterate through the word and set the value in the array that correlates to the letter as true. If the index is already set to true, return false since the letter already exists in the word. This trades some memory for O(n) speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first function you return true if the first character is not equal to the second character, in order to fix it you should change:

```
function checkLetters(word){
    var constant = 0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
            if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j)){
                return false;
                break;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

to:

```
function checkLetters(word){
    var constant = 0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
            if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j)){
                return false;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And second, since we can't see where did you declare `library` in the code that you posted here, I believe that it's probably defined somewhere as `var` (local variable) which means that if you want to be able to use it inside some other function you should pass it.

**UPDATE:**
About `library` - try to change the code as follows:

```
$('#noQ').click(function(library) {
    $('.yesNo').remove();
    $('#winQuestion').remove();
    var splitCompChoice = compFinalChoice.split('');
    var constant = 0;
    var possibleAnswers = [];
    for(var k=0;k<8939;k++){
        for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
            if(library[k].indexOf(splitCompChoice[i]) > -1){
                constant++;
                if(constant = 5 && checkLetters(library[k]) == true){
                    possibleAnswers.push(library[k]);
                }
            }
        }
}(library));
```

Comment: It's the very first thing in my code, I don't see how it could be a local variable.

Comment: @ThomasNocera in that case, see the `UPDATE` section of the answer

Comment: still no luck getting this "TypeError: library[k] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

if(library[k].indexOf(splitCompChoice[i]) > -1){"

Comment: before `if(compPrompt == 5...` try to `alert(library);` and see if it's define there

Comment: Try to post your code using: http://jsfiddle.net/ (post here a link) -  it's impossible to debug it without having the full code.

Comment: That actually works... all you have to do is change the "framework" section to work with jQuery, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/N5537/

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see any changes on yours.

Comment: There are no changes, but if you'll look at the *Frameworks & Extensions* section - you'll see that jQuery is turned on. I also tested it on .html file on my computer and library is recognized there.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of getting passed your if statement when the checkLetters function returns false, I would change the statement from

`if(compPrompt == 5 && checkLetters(compChoice) == true)`

to

```
if(compPrompt == 5 && checkLetters(compChoice))
```